# How can I determine if a C++ object has been deallocated?

Tags: c++

I have a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373686/unable-to-catch-c-exception-using-catch) that was answered in which I describe difficulties catching an exception when I try to access an object that has been deallocated by a third-party function.  The function sometimes does and sometimes doesn't deallocate the object.

In order to avoid having to use a try/catch block to catch the SEH Exception as described in the previous question, I need to be able to tell whether the object has been deallocated or not.

How can I determine if a C++ object has been deallocated or is still a valid pointer?

Comment: If the third-party library doesn't tell you if the object was deleted or not, it's time to get another library.

Answer (score 12):

You can't easily tell just by looking at the memory location if the object is still allocated or not. There might be some black magic tricks to do that, but a much cleaner way would be to build a call-back mechanism into the object's destructor.

Comment: I don't control the object definition - it is an object returned from the third-party dll.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're asking the wrong question. The question really ought to be:

***Why do I feel like I need to look at some address in order to find out whether the pointer pointing there refers to an object or to the garbage left after an ex-object was deleted?***

Honestly, you shouldn't be in that situation. If an object is deleted, why are you left with a pointer to its ex-address? Ideally, the pointer should be out of scope. If that isn't possible in your code, it should have been set to `NULL`.

Comment: I would revise your statement...   I shouldn't BE PUT in that position.  Unfortunately, that's the position I've been put in by the third party code.  Sometimes it frees it and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Ouch. A 3rd-party lib that sometimes hands out a pointer to an already deleted object? And you can't file a bug report? And the lib is still worth using? That sounds like a very bad situation.

Comment: It might be a wrong question in the context of writing the program, but it is a right question in the context of writing a test unit where you want to find out if the pointer is actually deleted as it should.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If the function you're using doesn't give you ways of knowing whether or not it deallocated the object itself, there's no way you can find out.

Edit: Well, unless the object in question is an instance of your own class and you can modify the destructor like Adrian suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, at least not in a standard way. There is, as far as I know, no requirement that the heap manager be able to detect if an address has been previously returned.

If there was, there would be no need to make it undefined what `delete` is to do with invalid pointers.

Comment: I think you could override malloc and free to achieve something like that, but that's what I would call black magic...

Answer (score 0):

If you control all the code that accesses your object, then the proper way is to use boost::shared_ptr to manage the lifetime of the object and then boost::weak_ptr for any references that you expect to remain after the object is deleted.

Looking at your other question about a third party library though, you may be stuck.  If the library is prone to deleting the object as a side effect of other options, then likely you're not intended to keep those pointers around.  Is there a reason that you can't re-fetch the object any time you need it, or at least after doing anything that may have deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

create a destructor that notifies upon desrtruction. It could even toggle a bool, if you wanted to check it during runtime.

```
class free
{

public:

    ~free() { cout << "Im being freed " << endl; } //destructor output
};
```

This will output in console that its being freed. After being freed, any reference to it will be undefined behaviour, even if it appears to exist.