# C++ - creating safe const char* contructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I'm creating a class that has a constructor intialized from `const char*` which should safely construct an object using data provided in the buffer which should contain a string. My worries are, that the user can use this constructor with wrong data, e.g. `NULL` pointer or pointer to not-allocated memory or something like that. The point is, in that case I want to finish creating object (which will be in undefined, but correct state), without causing segfault if, for example, user sent me a pointer to data I shouldn't read. I thought of sending all input validation to `std::string` constructor, so the constructor would look like this:

```
Foo(const char *s) : Foo(std::string(s)) {}
```

But my teacher called this a "wrong idea". So, what is the proper way to deal with this situation then?

One more thing, I can't use exceptions in that case (this is part of my homework assignment in course which hasn't taught it yet).

Comment: You do not need this - the compiler is clever enough to figure out to use the `foo(std::string)` constructor for you

Comment: Actually - I need this. I need the constructor `foo(std::string)` to be `explicit`, to prevent something like `foo x = "bar"`.

Comment: “undefined, but correct state” seems like a contradiction in terms. In fact, rather than creating an undefined object you should *almost certainly* throw an exception in the constructor to prevent a faulty object from being created. This depends on the use-case of course, but it’s so often the correct solution that I’d almost call it an absolute law.

Comment: @qiubit Then declare it `explicit`, this works perfectly fine.

Comment: So valid usage should be only `Foo foo("aaaaa");` ?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree with you, but I can't use exceptions yet, see my update

Comment: tell your teacher, since it is c++ it is a "wrong idea" to use char*...

Comment: Actually in that case there is no other way ;) I'm implementing BigInteger library and I want to prevent something like `BigInt x = 3 + "3"` or `BigInt x = "3"` from happening (compilation error). So I need to set `std::string` constructor explicit, but that means compiler can't allow for BigInt x("1234") as its treating "1234" as const char* literal and it can't cast it to string. That means I NEED `const char*` constructor.

Comment: char* is used quite a bit in C++ including communications via TCP/IP or other protocols.  There is a very valuable lesson to be learned here and using a char* is a very simple way to teach it.  qiubit, you may want to ask your teacher what he/she wants you to learn here rather than simply focusing on the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that there are some things you absolutely cannot check for.  The biggest of the group is a pointer to invalid memory.  For example :

```
char* blarg = new char[50];
delete blarg;
Foo(blarg);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373994/how-can-i-determine-if-a-c-object-has-been-deallocated) is another conversation about what you're asking.  Some good answers are there but they basically say the same thing.  When dealing with a pointer input there is no way to be 100% sure the user didn't do something stupid like calling delete on the pointer before passing it in.

Answer (score 2):

> My worries are, that the user can use this constructor with wrong data, e.g. NULL pointer or pointer to not-allocated memory or something like that. The point is, in that case I want to finish creating object (which will be in undefined, but correct state)

It's impossible to detect if a pointer is valid. It's has to be the responsibility of the caller to guarantee that it points to allocated memory.

However, you *can* detect if a pointer is null. You can check that and if it is, then set the state of the object without dereferencing the pointer.

> I thought of sending all input validation to std::string constructor
>
> But my teacher called this a "wrong idea".

Your teacher is correct. That won't help because `std::string` also requires and assumes that the input is valid. Constructing it with an invalid pointer leads to undefined behaviour.

> So, what is the proper way to deal with this situation then?

Simply requiring the caller to guarantee the validity of the pointer is the right thing to - and all you can - do. If you want to check for null, feel free to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error in your constructor, `throw`.  That's what it's there for.  The object *isn't* constructed and the client (who passed in the erroneous pointer) is properly told so.

Comment: This is not really an answer since OP has clearly stated he can't use exceptions

Comment: see his update `One more thing, I can't use exceptions in that case`.

Comment: Then he should use whatever equivalent his framework uses to replace exceptions.

Comment: His TEACHER, as part of his HOMEWORK assignment, has said that he CANNOT do that.

Comment: @soulsabr His TEACHER should go down to the clue boutique and buy a FRIGGIN clue.This isn't C++.

Comment: Can you read?  TITLE : C++ - creating safe const char* constructor.  Sounds pretty C++ to me but who knows; it may be a foreign language.  Do you know the purpose of having assignments like this?  It is to teach students the basics of software and how the language works.  Of course there are a zillion ways to do this but this is academic work; it doesn't have to make 100% sense so long as the student learns lesson being taught.  Please visit the boutique yourself as you're obviously in need.

Comment: @soulsabr Yes, and C++ is designed in such a way that in this scenario you `throw`.  Anything else isn't going to be *safe* and should have a very solid justification for doing so and is a C++ workaround.

Comment: try
 {
  char* blarg = new char;
  *blarg = 'n';
  delete blarg;
  std::cout << "blarg " << *blarg << std::endl;
 }
 catch (...)
 { }

This does not throw an exception but simply prints out whatever the hell is in memory at the time of access.  If his constructor were to do something similar it would fail without an exception or a crash; the behavior would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check that your class accept as arguments only `std::string`
and `const char[]` you can write something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:

    template<typename U>
    Foo(U &&val, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type, std::string>::value ||
        std::is_array<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(val)>::type>::value, void>::type* = nullptr): field_(val) {}
private:
    std::string field_;
};
```

Then:

```
Foo foo("aa");//accept
std::string str("bb");
Foo foo2(str);//accept
Foo fnull(NULL);//compile time error
```

of course this solution not work if you want pass just pointer to `char`.